# How to run powershell commands in administrative mode using jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have a **.ps1** file which needs to be run in administrative mode for it to work. But unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do that using Jenkins. Currently I am running this powershell command in execute batch command on Jenkins with all possible options. But it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy hack to solve this was indeed adding a **.bat** file that was run from the Jenkins(Execute windows batch command). The bat file had following command which did run the powershell script with elevated(admin) rights

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File your_script.ps1 --settings_skipverification=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute it with `Invoke-Command` via Jenkins.

```
Invoke-command -FilePath Script.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins is running as service, you can open `services.msc` and right click on Jenkins. Then click `Properties`, go to `Logon` tab, check mark `This account` and enter username and password which has admin privileges. Stop and Start Jenkins service.

From now on when you will run powershell commands in Jenkins, they will be run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke with "Execute powershell step" as

```
$arg = "-file C:\filename.ps1"
start-process powershell -verb runas –argumentlist $arg
```