# Jenkins Can't Run Powershell IIS Script as Admin

Tags: powershell, iis, jenkins-pipeline

I have some jenkins powershell IIS scripts. I need to run them as admin in jenkins pipeline to make it work. When I try it from jenkins it gives me "Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions". But when I run it from my local ps as admin, it works perfectly. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You have to review how you configured the Jenkins agent. If it's not running under a suitable account (usually local system is needed), what you see is expected.

Comment: You can try to add a bat file with command in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912297/how-to-run-powershell-commands-in-administrative-mode-using-jenkins). It can improve the permission.